# Use of \\minted@pygmentize doesn't match its definition

Tags: minted, python

Having followed the installation instructions for the minted package ([CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/)), I keep encountering the error, and variations thereof, listed in the title when trying to compile the document.

The relevant preamble:

```
\usepackage{./ExtraPackages/minted/minted}
```

The call to use minted:

```
    \appendix
    \chapter{Appendices}
    \section*{Python Source Code}
    \label{app: SourceCode}
    \begin{minted}
        \inputminted{python}{SourceCode/strainPOSCAR.py}
    \end{minted}
```

I have something of a tight deadline so any help would be particularly appreciated :-).

Comment: Are you sure that you need `\begin{minted}` and `\end{minted}` around `\inputminted`?

Comment: Lol - thanks very much. That was a legacy from before I found out about `\inputminted`. Thanks again! Edit: If you want to make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\inputminted` command implicitly encloses the code in the correct environment:

```
\section*{Python Source Code}
\label{app: SourceCode}

\inputminted{python}{SourceCode/strainPOSCAR.py}
```